# VueJS: Set variable name using string

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to set a variable `myvar` using a string in the example below ?

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            myvar: 'foo'
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried this which didn't work:

```
eval('myvar'): 'foo'
```

Comment: you can use `this['myvar'] = 'foo';`

Comment: @DerekPollard I get a syntax error if I do that : `Unexpected keyword 'this'`

Comment: where are you using this at? you should probably be doing it in a method

Comment: I'm just wondering if it's possible to do it.

Comment: Yeah it's possible for sure, in what scope are you trying to set the variable? Show us an example.

Comment: `this.myvar = 'foo';`

Comment: @maxagaz - did one of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very crude and basic example of how you would accomplish something like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      myVar: 'hello'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeVal(varName, newValue) {
      this[varName] = newValue;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{myVar}}
  <button @click="changeVal('myVar', 'world')">change myVar</button>
</div>
```

Here, we are utilizing a method that takes the name of the variable and the value to change it to - then passing it to the current vue model instance (represented by `this` inside of methods) to modify the value of the dynamic variable name.

Answer (score -3):

To change data, you just need to modify it like you would any other mutable variable. It depends how your component is set up. Looking at the docs (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties), one way of doing it is like this (modified example from the above link):

```js
const vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myvar: 'foo'
  },
  template: '<div>{{ myvar }}</div>'
})

vue.myvar = 'bar'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If you want to do it from a method (e.g. calling a method from within a template), refer to it with the `this` keyword:

```js
const vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myvar: 'foo'
  },
  template: '<div><div>{{ myvar }}</div><button @click="changeMe">Click Me</button></div>',
  methods: {
    changeMe() {
      this.myvar = 'bar'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```