# How to Dynamically change variables in Vue Js with a For Loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objects, nuxt.js

Basically I have 5 foodNames variables. I want to change their values dynamically.
Something like this:

```
        foodName1: '',
        foodAmount1: '',
        foodName2: '',
        foodAmount2: '',
        foodName3: '',
        foodAmount3: '',
        foodName4: '',
        foodAmount4: '',
        foodName5: '',
        foodAmount5: '',


addFood() {

      for (i=1; i < this.n; i++) {

       this.list.push(this.foodName{i});
       this.list.push(this.foodAmount{i});
       this.foods.push(this.list);
       this.list= [];
       this.foodName{i} = '';
       this.foodAmount{i} = '';
   }
        
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Without any context we can't help you

Comment: I only need to know how to use the 'i' of the for loop in the variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS: Set variable name using string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691495/vuejs-set-variable-name-using-string)

Answer (score 0):

you should put your food names in an array and access it with foodName[i]

Answer (score 0):

You can access object property names dynamically using brackets:

```
this["foodName"+i] = "";
```

Comment: it says 'i' is not defined

Comment: It says 'foodName' isn't defined on the instance.

Comment: Then you need to provide more code to see where the problem lies.